# How to show cumulative growth in a metric over dates using sql and grouping by date?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, amazon-redshift

I'd like to show cumulative growth in a metric over a date, while also grouping for date, so that the date only occurs once in the table

I have the following data set:

> data =
>   [{'date':'2016-01-01','value':'1'},{'date':'2016-01-01','value':'3'},{'date':'2016-01-02','value':'3'},{'date':'2016-01-02','value':'2'}]

The following query is producing the below table:

```
select 
date, 
sum(value) over (order by date rows unbounded preceding) as value
from data
group by 
date, 
value
```

Below is my table

```
date        value       
2016-01-01  1   
2016-01-01  4
2016-01-02  7    
2016-01-02  9
```

However, I want to produce the following table:

```
date        value       
2016-01-01  4   
2016-01-02  9
```

When I try the following query and do not group by value, I get the below error:

```
select 
date, 
sum(value) over (order by date rows unbounded preceding) as value
from data
group by 
date
```

ERROR:

> column "value" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an
>   aggregate function

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Why have you tagged this as MySQL, SQL Server AND Redshift? Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sum values by dates before calculating running total?

```
select date, 
    sum(value) over (order by date) as value
from (
    select date, sum(value) as value
    from data
    group by date
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I could think of would be removing the rows unbound preceding and include a distinct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [date]
    ,SUM([value]) OVER (ORDER BY [date]) AS [value]
FROM @tbl
```

That said, you could also subquery with row_number.

```
SELECT
    [date]
    ,[value]
FROM (
    SELECT
        [date]
        ,SUM([value]) OVER (ORDER BY [date]) AS [value]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [date] ORDER BY [value] DESC) AS [row]
    FROM @tbl
    ) tbl
WHERE [row] = 1
```